# OpenLayers 3 TileCache causing browser to run out of memory with CQL filters

Tags: javascript, caching, openlayers-3

I'm currently running OpenLayers 3.2.1. I have a wms tile layer displaying various polygons across a map and a wms tile layer displaying state boundaries. The goal is for the user to be able to click on a state, retrieve the coordinates of the state boundary in a getFeatureInfo request, then use the coordinates to filter the first layer to only show polygons within that state.

With the large number of points in each polygon, the url for a layer with a CQL filter was far past the url length limit. Using the tileLoadFunction I converted the request to a POST to bypass it. Taken from this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175057/openlayers-3-wms-styling-using-sld-body-and-post-request

Everything is working and the first layer is properly being filtered when clicking a state. The problem is after clicking the amount of memory used by the TileCache skyrockets because the urls stored in it are so long. After the first click the entire application is slowed tremendously. A few clicks later and the browser crashes. Using chrome, a comparison between a before and after snapshot shows an increase of 179MB purely from the storage of these urls in the TileCache.

I've tried to prevent the caching but OpenLayers requires the cache to load the layers. I've tried to clear out the cache after the layer is loaded but in my version there seems to be no definite way to know the exact moment a layer has finished loading. I tried clearing out the cache after a long timeout but for some reason the cache kept filling up afterwards. Last I tried setting an interval to clear the cache periodically but the cache just continues to fill up to the original point.

Here is the code scaled down:

```
var params = getWMSParams(jsonLayerConfig, map);
var options = {
    url: geoserverUrl,
    params: params,
    tileLoadFunction: function(image, src) {
        convertToPost(image, src);
    }
};

var source = new ol.source.TileWMS(options);

var polygonLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source : source
});

// states layer is created the same way then both are added to map.

var getCqlGeometry = function(coords) {
    var geomString = '';
    if (typeof(coords[0]) === 'number') {
        geomString = coords[0] + ' ' + coords[1];
    } else {
        var geomString = '(';
        var subGeoms = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = coords.length; i < len; i+=1) {
            var coord = coords[i];
            subGeoms.push(getCqlGeometry(coord));
        }
        geomString += subGeoms.join(',') + ')';
    }
    return geomString;
}

var setCqlFilter = function(featureInfo) {
    var geomString = getCqlGeometry(featureInfo.coords);
    var cqlFilter = "WITHIN(geom,MULTIPOLYGON"+geomString+")";

    // Some code here updates the layers in the map.
}

map.on('click', function(event) {
    var featureInfo = getFeatureInfo(event.coordinate);
    setCqlFilter(featureInfo);
});

var convertToPost = function(image, src) {
    var img = image.getImage();
    if (typeof window.btoa === 'function') {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = src.substr(0, src.indexOf('?'));
        var params = src.substring(src.indexOf('?')+1);
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);

        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(this.response);
                var i = uInt8Array.length;
                var binaryString = new Array(i);
                while (i--) {
                    binaryString[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
                }
                var data = binaryString.join('');
                var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type');
                if (type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
                    img.src = 'data:' + type + ';base64,' + window.btoa(data);
                }
                uInt8Array = null;
            }
        };
        //SET THE PROPER HEADERS AND FINALLY SEND THE PARAMETERS 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send(params);
    } else {
        img.src = src;
    }
}
```

It's a possibility for me to update to the latest OpenLayers 3 version (3.19.1 at time of writing) but I'll need a good enough reason to give my employers.

**EDIT:**

I was able to get it working based on ahocevar's comment. Since each layer in the json layer configurations are assigned an auto-generated id, I added that id to the layers params, parsed the url for that parameter in the tileLoadFunction, then retrieved the json configuration for that layer (json configuration also holds the cql filter). I would still prefer a way to prevent caching but for now this solution will work. Thanks ahocevar.

Comment: Why don't you just store the CQL filter as value on the layer (`layer.set('filter', yourCQLhere)`) and use that in the tileLoadFunction, instead of setting it as part of the `PARAMS` of the layer? So it won't end up in the URL.

Comment: It seems I can't access the associated layer in the tileLoadFunction. What it gives me instead is an instance of ol.imageTile. The layers that are added to the map are dynamically assigned through a set of layer configurations that can be added or removed at any time asynchronously so without a direct reference I have no way of knowing which layer is being loaded at that time.